# Read a file into an associative array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I want to be able to read the file into an associative array where I can access the elements by the column head name.

My file is formatted as follows:

```
KeyName    Val1Name   Val2Name  ...  ValMName
Key1       Val1-1     Val2-1    ...  ValM-1
Key2       Val1-2     Val2-2    ...  ValM-2   
Key3       Val1-3     Val2-3    ...  ValM-3
..         ..         ..        ..    ..
KeyN       Val1-N     Val2-N    ...  ValM-N
```

The only problem is I don't have a clue how to do it. So far I have:

```
scores = File.read("scores.txt")
lines = scores.split("\n")
lines.each { |x|
  y = x.to_s.split(' ')
}
```

Which gets close to what I want, but still am unable to get it into the format that is usable for me.

Comment: are the columns separated by tabs or a definite number of spaces??

Comment: They look like they're just an indefinite number of spaces. Definitely NOT tabs though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done in 3 lines (This is why I love Ruby)

```
scores = File.readlines('/scripts/test.txt').map{|l| l.split(/\s+/)}
headers = scores.shift
scores.map!{|score|Hash[headers.zip(score)]}
```

now `scores` contains your hash array

Here is a verbose explanation

```
#open the file and read 
#then split on new line 
#then create an array of each line by splitting on space and stripping additional whitespace
scores = File.open('scores.txt', &:read).split("\n").map{|l| l.split(" ").map(&:strip)}
#shift the array to capture the header row
headers = scores.shift
#initialize an Array to hold the score hashs
scores_hash_array = []
#loop through each line
scores.each do |score|
  #map the header value based on index with the line value 
  scores_hash_array << Hash[score.map.with_index{|l,i| [headers[i],l]}]
end
#=>[{"KeyName"=>"Key1", "Val1Name"=>"Val1-1", "Val2Name"=>"Val2-1", "..."=>"...", "ValMName"=>"ValM-1"},
    {"KeyName"=>"Key2", "Val1Name"=>"Val1-2", "Val2Name"=>"Val2-2", "..."=>"...", "ValMName"=>"ValM-2"},
    {"KeyName"=>"Key3", "Val1Name"=>"Val1-3", "Val2Name"=>"Val2-3", "..."=>"...", "ValMName"=>"ValM-3"},
    {"KeyName"=>"..", "Val1Name"=>"..", "Val2Name"=>"..", "..."=>"..", "ValMName"=>".."},
    {"KeyName"=>"KeyN", "Val1Name"=>"Val1-N", "Val2Name"=>"Val2-N", "..."=>"...", "ValMName"=>"ValM-N"}]
```

`scores_hash_array` now has a hash for each row in the sheet.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks so much!
Now how would I use the values in the scores_hash_array as initialization values for an object?
IE  obj = obj.new(key1,val1-1,val2-1,val3-1... valN-1)
and then hash those objects based on the key.
Remember I'm totally coming at this with a C-language mentality.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = File.open("scores.txt") #get an instance of the file
first_line = f.gets.chomp #get the first line in the file (header)
first_line_array = first_line.split(/\s+/) #split the first line in the file via whitespace(s)
array_of_hash_maps = f.readlines.map do |line| 
                       Hash[first_line_array.zip(line.split(/\s+/))]
                     end
#read the remaining lines of the file via `IO#readlines` into an array, split each read line by whitespace(s) into an array, and zip the first line with them, then convert it into a `Hash` object, and return a collection of the `Hash` objects
f.close #close the file

puts array_of_hash_maps #print the collection of the Hash objects to stdout
```

Comment: That's precisely what I needed, thanks so much. Ruby is just so different from everything I've ever done. :)

Comment: no need to hold the file open you can read the whole thing immediately into an array using `File.readlines`

Comment: @engineersmnky you need the first line to use a key, that's what `first_line = f.gets.chomp` does, and leaves you with the remaining lines

Comment: yes but you don't need to hold the file open when you could use `shift` on the array. Take a look at my answer to see what I mean

Comment: @engineersmnky you are right, but I gave the solution that occurred to me first

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
enter code here
fh = File.open("scores.txt","r")
rh={} #result Hash
fh.readlines.each{|line|
kv=line.split(/\s+/)
puts kv.length
rh[kv[0]] = kv[1..kv.length-1].join(",") #***store the values joined by ","
}
puts rh.inspect
fh.close
```

If you want to get an array of values,replace the last line in loop by 
    rh[kv[0]] = kv[1..kv.length-1]